# Birt cannot find correct font files in PDF report

Tags: java, eclipse, report, birt

I'm using **Birt** for making reports using Tomcat.

When i deployed the birt design to my Linux server , the generated pdf is **missing the correct fonts**.

I also tried adding font path in **fontsConfig.xml** as said in this [link](http://www.birt-exchange.org/forum/index.php/topic/28406-fonts-rendered-different-when-generating-pdf-report/) 
 . But no luck...

My **fontsConfig.xml** file looks like this :

```
....
<font-paths>     
     <path path="path/to/fonts/folder" />    
....
```

---

**How can i tell to Birt about the Fonts location?**

---

Optionally i can put correct font files in JRE/lib/fonts folder & it works but i have no permission for that in my production server...

Comment: Which version of Birt are you using and how you use BIRT (as standalone or as embeeded engine)&

Comment: i use birt-runtime-4_2_2..i use the 'WebViewerExample' that come with BIRT runtime.I put my .rptdesign files inside that and host to my Tomcat server.

Answer (score 1):

Under Linux (CentOS), I use the standard folder `/usr/share/fonts/msttcore` listed in builtin `fontsConfig.xml`.

I use this:

```
rpm -i https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/mscorefonts2/rpms/msttcore-fonts-installer-2.6-1.noarch.rpm
```

in order to install the fonts, as explained [here](http://mscorefonts2.sourceforge.net/).